# Not able to load dynamically the CDN of jquery, bootstrap, D3.js, knockout.js using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

Not able to load dynamically the CDN of jquery, bootstrap, D3.js, knockout.js using jquery. i am using jquerycdn variable to pass to the loadscript() when checkjquery() is false. But when i am passing still the jquery CDN is not loading. Same issue facing with the remaining files like bootstrap, D3.js, knockout.js etc. All these file CDN's are kept in one js file.

**Please check the below code:-**

```
this.jqueryCDN = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"

Initialize.prototype.checkJQuery = function () {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

if (!this.checkJQuery ()) {
                console.log("jquerynot available")               
                this.loadJQuery ();
                if (!this.checkJQuery ()) {
                    throw "Error loading jquery"
                }
            } else {
                console.log("jquery available")
            }

Initialize.prototype.loadJQuery = function () {
//    var js_code = atob(this.jqueryStr);
//    eval(js_code);
    this.loadScript(this.jqueryCDN);
};

Initialize.prototype.loadScript = function (src) {
    var my_awesome_script = document.createElement('script');
    my_awesome_script.setAttribute('src', src);
    document.head.appendChild(my_awesome_script);
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors on your browser's console ?

Comment: $ is not defined.{It means i guess jquery not loaded}.

Comment: Have you tried adding the CDN for jQuery in your HTML instead of in your JS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give jQuery time to load before checking to see that it's loaded. An onload trigger would be better than timeout, but here's your code working.

```js
function Initialize() {
  var self = this;
  this.jqueryCDN = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
  if (!this.checkJQuery()) {
    console.log("jquery not available")
    this.loadJQuery();
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!self.checkJQuery()) {
        throw "Error loading jquery"
      } else {
        alert("jQuery loaded!");
      }
    }, 2500);
  } else {
    console.log("jquery available")
  }
}
Initialize.prototype.checkJQuery = function() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};


Initialize.prototype.loadJQuery = function() {
  //    var js_code = atob(this.jqueryStr);
  //    eval(js_code);
  this.loadScript(this.jqueryCDN);
};

Initialize.prototype.loadScript = function(src) {
  var my_awesome_script = document.createElement('script');
  my_awesome_script.setAttribute('src', src);
  document.body.appendChild(my_awesome_script);
}

var i = new Initialize();
```

You might also look at [this approach](http://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/).